# TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to access data from OpenWeather API and it has nested objects and I keep getting the error trying to access data in these nested objects. I can access values from the parent object but no from nested ones.

this is me passing data to the component.

```
  const Card = ({ cardRef }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    setData({ ...cardRef });
    console.log(data.main.temp);
  }, [cardRef]);
```

I can access data.main but not data.main.temp

below in the data being passed

```
    {
    "coord": {
        "lon": -0.2,
        "lat": 5.56
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 304.15,
        "feels_like": 304.86,
        "temp_min": 304.15,
        "temp_max": 304.15,
        "pressure": 1011,
        "humidity": 66
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.2,
        "deg": 190
    },
    "rain": {
        "1h": 0.29
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 20
    },
    "dt": 1607092023,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 1126,
        "country": "GH",
        "sunrise": 1607061413,
        "sunset": 1607103947
    },
    "timezone": 0,
    "id": 2306104,
    "name": "Accra",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `setData` is the asynchronous method, you can't get the updated value of `data` immediatley after `setData`.

```
  const Card = ({ cardRef }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    setData({ ...cardRef });
    console.log(data.main.temp); // data is still the old value which is initial empty {} value, so `data.main` is undefined and `data.main.temp` will be error.
  }, [cardRef]);
```

You should get it inside useEffect with adding a `data` dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data.main) { // Make sure that you need to check if `data.main` is not undefined before referring `data.main.temp`.
    console.log(data.main.temp);
  }
}, [data]);
```

Comment: got an infinite loop

Comment: where are you getting an infinite loop? second useEffect that console.log(data.main.temp) ?

Comment: and its setData(cardRef) not setData({..cardRef})

Comment: i just followed based on your try, so you can update it as you want. setData(cardRef)